# organizing source code in filesystem on mac osx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, version-control, code-organization

Any recommendations on a good way to organize source code on mac osx? I'm usually doing ruby or ruby on rails development and I have a lot of past projects in classic asp and asp.net MVC C#. I also have a lot of git repos I download from github.

I want some general guidlines but I do have a few specific questions.

Should I put my source code files under my user. So like this

```
/Users/Brand/MySourceFiles/...
```

Or should I put it under the root? I prefer the root but dunno if that's a bad idea.

```
/MySourceFiles/...
```

Should I keep my website project separate from my non-website projects?

For website projects I have a lot of photoshop files, where should those go?

Any reason I should keep my .net and rails projects in different folders? Like one for asp.net and one for rails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Under your user", i.e., in your home directory. Many folks like to have a `src` directory in their home directory which they use for source code. I don't think you'll find any consensus on how to organize that `src` folder -- most of the time it's just flat, with many subdirectories in it.

Comment: could you comment on why it's better than having it outside the home dir? Personally, I'd like it if the path were just /src instead of /User/Brand/src. But I guess I could setup a symlink. hrmmm...

Comment: Mac OS X, like any UNIX, is fundamentally a multi-user OS. The filesystem is designed around this idea: there is a specific place where the files for each user belong; everything else is assumed to be owned by the system or some service. It's true that nothing would *prevent* you from putting your code at the root -- it's your machine, after all -- but it's not how things are usually done.

Comment: If it's under your home directory, you'll by default have full permissions. (Although root can change this.)  If you put it somewhere else in the filesystem, a number of reasonable things can run that create conflict.  I'm not sure what Fix Permissions would do with your custom top-level directory.  /opt is another...option, but most people end up putting it in their home directory under src, Projects (per Xcode), IdeaProjects, or whatever their tools of choice prefer.